# LibVlc Disable subtitle track

Tags: android, libvlc

I would like to disable a subtitle track in LibVlc.
This is how I set one:

```
vlcPlayer.setSpuTrack(id);
```

I already tried setting the id to -1 and a high value like 99 but the subtitle track was still there.

I've read about the command

```
--no-spu
```

but I don't know how to enter a command into my LibVlc instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am up to solving the same issue.
`setSpuTrack(-1)` works but only if its called after `MediaPlayer.Event.Playing` event has been received.
If you find a better solution to this issue please share it with me.

Ive just found better way to disable subtitles.
You need to use `Media.addOption` method to add `--sub-track-id=<integer>` option.
Unfortunately it wont work if you use it with -1 so i use it with Integer.MAX_VALUE

```java
final Media media = new Media(mLibVLC, uri);
final String subtitleTrackOption = MessageFormat.format(":sub-track-id={0}", String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
media.addOption(subtitleTrackOption);
mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
```

You can see more on how ive done this [here](https://github.com/Stremio/react-native-vlc2/pull/4/commits/e5646acab6423ceb328c31eaeac3200d6ba0b91f)